# Answer is 8 but how?

Tags: c, recursion

How does the following code work?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
void main () {
    int n = 6, d;
    int func (int n) {
        int x, y;
        if (n <= 1)
            return n;
        x = func (n - 1);
        y = func (n - 2);
        return (x + y);
    }
    d = func (6);
    printf ("%d", d);
}
```

The answer is 8 but don't know why? please explain step wise step.

Comment: Fibonacci numbers : 0 1 1 2 3 5 8:func(6) => func(5)+func(4) => 3+5

Comment: @Chief Two Pencils : fixed......

Comment: @bluepix: but how its using fibonacci numbers?

Comment: BTW: 1. `return` is not a function, don't use parentheses. 2. `main` has return-type `int` (and `main` has an implicit `return 0;` at the end since C99). 3. And functions have to be at the global scope, you are using a GCC extension there.

Comment: @AakashJohari Rather than using, `func` to calculate the Fibonacci numbers of the specified number.

Comment: <conio.h>` is non-standard, and you're not using anything declared in it; drop the `#include` directive. Print a newline at the end of your output: `printf("%d\n", d);` `void main()` should be `int main(void)`; if your textbook told you to use `void main()`, burn it.

Comment: I'll just mention that simple recursion is a horribly inefficient way to compute Fibonacci numbers. The number of calls increases exponentially with the size of the argument. If your goal is to learn about recursion, it's fine; if your goal is to generate Fibonacci numbers, there are much better ways.

Comment: @KeithThompson au contraire, the program may be running in an embedded environment (a lot of which still use c89), in which case a void main return type makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @Toby: I seriously doubt that the OP is working in an embedded environment; `<conio.h>` is unlikely to be available. Even in an embedded environment, `void main()`, or preferably `void main(void)`, makes sense only if the implementation documents it as the correct form.

Comment: @KeithThompson ah, missed the pesky conio.h include!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's build an execution tree for `func(n)`. If it's called with `n <= 1`, it returns `n`. Otherwise, it returns `func(n-1)+func(n-2)`.

So,

```
func(6)=
func(5)+func(4)=
func(4)+func(3)+func(3)+func(2)=
func(3)+func(2)+func(2)+func(1)+func(2)+func(1)+func(1)+func(0)=
func(2)+func(1)+func(1)+func(0)+func(1)+func(0)+func(1)+func(1)+func(0)+func(1)+func(1)+func(0)=
func(1)+func(0)+func(1)+func(1)+func(0)+func(1)+func(0)+func(1)+func(1)+func(0)+func(1)+func(1)+func(0)=
1+0+1+1+0+1+0+1+1+0+1+1+0=
8
```

Answer (score 1):

Recursive functions often work in ways that are obscured to new users of recursive functions. One of the best ways to learn the logic of a recursive function is to look at what is actually taking place. This is why you often hear that 'recursive functions are **less readable** than ordinary functions' Take a look at the actual flow:

```
//how the code is working?
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <conio.h>
int main () {
    int n = 6, d;
    int func (int n) {
        printf (" entering func (%d)\n", n);
        int x, y;
        if (n <= 1)
            return n;
        x = func (n - 1);
        printf ("  x = %d\n", x);
        y = func (n - 2);
        printf ("  y = %d\n", y);
        printf ("    returning (%d + %d) = %d\n", x, y, x + y);
        return (x + y);
    }
    d = func (n);
    printf ("%d", d);
    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/fun6
 entering func (6)
 entering func (5)
 entering func (4)
 entering func (3)
 entering func (2)
 entering func (1)
  x = 1
 entering func (0)
  y = 0
    returning (1 + 0) = 1
  x = 1
 entering func (1)
  y = 1
    returning (1 + 1) = 2
  x = 2
 entering func (2)
 entering func (1)
  x = 1
 entering func (0)
  y = 0
    returning (1 + 0) = 1
  y = 1
    returning (2 + 1) = 3
  x = 3
 entering func (3)
 entering func (2)
 entering func (1)
  x = 1
 entering func (0)
  y = 0
    returning (1 + 0) = 1
  x = 1
 entering func (1)
  y = 1
    returning (1 + 1) = 2
  y = 2
    returning (3 + 2) = 5
  x = 5
 entering func (4)
 entering func (3)
 entering func (2)
 entering func (1)
  x = 1
 entering func (0)
  y = 0
    returning (1 + 0) = 1
  x = 1
 entering func (1)
  y = 1
    returning (1 + 1) = 2
  x = 2
 entering func (2)
 entering func (1)
  x = 1
 entering func (0)
  y = 0
    returning (1 + 0) = 1
  y = 1
    returning (2 + 1) = 3
  y = 3
    returning (5 + 3) = 8
```